# Problems using double lists

Tags: r, nested-lists

I'm having trouble trying to implement a double list in R. If one sublist is initialized with just one element then after I tried to add more elements I get the error message:

> more elements supplied than there are to replace

Here is an example:

```
#
# This is OK
#
a <- list()
a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]] <- c(10,20)
a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]] <- c(a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]], c(30,40))
```

And this is the output of a:

```
> a
$elem1
$elem1$elem2
[1] 10 20 30 40
```

But,

```
#
# This is giving error:
#
a <- list()
a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]] <- c(10)
a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]] <- c(a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]], c(30,40))

Error in a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]] <- c(a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]], c(30, 40)) : 
more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

and this is the output of a:

```
> a
$elem1
elem2 
10
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The first one is a list of list, while the second is just a list

Comment: it would be more helpful if you can update your question with the expected output. How do you visualize your output list..

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Now, I have updated the question by showing the output of 'a' in each case. I think that akrun is oriented but how can I solve it?

Comment: Try `a[["elem1"]]$elem2<-10` or `a$elem1$elem2<-10`

Comment: Thanks nicola. That works, but I need to use the [["elem2"]] notation, because in the actual code that value is variable, i.e., in the form of [[cname]] where cname can have different values.

Comment: Then make it in two steps: `a[["elem1"]]<-list()` and then `a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]]<-10`.

Comment: Or  you could do it in one step by `a[["elem1"]][["elem2"]] <- list(10)`.

Comment: Thanks DGKarlsson, but in my case nicola solution suits better to my purposes. Still, I have to work it a bit because I'm creating sublists on the fly inside a loop, but now I know how to overcome the problem. Your solution is giving different output. I think that it is a problem on the assumptions that R makes during assignments.